# How to find the positions that a number falls in-between in a set of sequential integers

Tags: python, list, for-loop, integer

I have an number variable and a sequential set of integers. As the number variable changes, I need to record what positions in the sequential set of integers the number variable falls in-between.

For example, if my set of integers is:

```
li = [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
```

And the number variable is:

```
num = 22.74
```

My desired output would be the positions in the list that `num` falls in-between:

```
2,3
```

I know that `li.index(22)` would return the position but only if that exact item is in the list. Haven't been able to come across how to find positions if the number falls in-between items.

I imagine a for loop that compares `num` to each of the neighboring position items in the list by checking if `num` falls in between those two integers could solve it. Something like:

```
for x and the following item in li:
    if x < num < the following item:
        positionone = x
        positiontwo = the following item
    else:
        continue
```

Just haven't been able to complete how this works, mainly by getting the next position of the list in replace of "*the following item*". Maybe there's a better way of figuring this? Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `22.74` is not integer.

Comment: What if `num` **is** integer? E.g. what should the result be if `num == 24`?

Comment: Updated the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: It will be enough to compare if your value is lower than current element and break loop execution in case if condition fails returning current index and previous index. To iterate over value with it's index you can use `enumerate()`.

Comment: is it possible to `num` stay over the `li` interval? For example `num=32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close with your basic logic.  You need to iterate through the list.  If you do it using the index, rather than the value, you'll be able to retrieve the positions you want.
Your basic logic is fine.

```
for idx in range(len(li)-1):
    if li[idx] < num < li[idx+1]:
        pos1, pos2 = idx, idx+1
```

Given that, I expect that you can solve the problem of equality as a special case, right?

Comment: I would avoid having `pos1, pos2` assigned conditionally. Maybe create a function that returns a `Tuple[Optional[int], Optional[int]]`. Also probably want to account for the special cases like `0.5, [1,2,3]` and `3.5, [1,2,3]`

Comment: Yes, there are many sophisticated ways to attack the problem, many that are hardier and more general.  My purpose (and, to some extent, that of Stack Overflow) is to get the student over the current blocking point.  For an appropriate beginner question (an oxymoron here), I keep the technology level to my guess at the class syllabus.

Comment: IMO `num > max(li)` or `num < min(li)` would be expected corner cases to think about. At the very least set `pos1, pos2 = None, None` before the loop or OP will probably start getting a lot of `NameError` raised.

Comment: This works great and gets me to where I needed. I can solve for events where the number is equivalent to a list item independently. Thank you!

Comment: @flakes thanks for identifying the potential hurdle. I've included `pos1, pos2 = None, None` above the loop in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to touch the ambiguities regarding `num` being integer or not. But I will give you the tool needed to answer your question.

Let `lo` and `hi` respectively be the lower and upper limit of your interest. Then, to get the indices of the number between these two is done as such:

```
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(li)
           if lo < x < hi]
```

Please note that I use `<` twice there. If you want the lower bound to be inclusive, replace the first `<` with `<=`. Similarly, if you want the upper bound to be inclusive replace the second `<` with `<=`. Or very generally:

```py
def indices_between(iterable, lo, hi, include_lo=False, include_hi=False):
    lo_req = (lambda x: lo <= x) if include_lo else (lambda x: lo < x)
    hi_req = (lambda x: x <= hi) if include_hi else (lambda x: x < hi)
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(iterable)
            if lo_req(x) and hi_req(x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare your number with each element and break loop if current element greater than your number:

```py
for index, current_element in enumerate(li):
    if current_element > num:
        position_one, position_two = index - 1 if index else index, index
        break
else:
    position_one, position_two = index, index
```

Answer (score 1):

A mathematical way of doing this is to subtract the number from the list and check for the two minimum absolute value. If `li` is a numpy array you can do this in one line:

```
li = np.array(li)
interval = sorted(np.abs(li-num).argsort()[:2])
```